# Transforming a point cloud from one space to another

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, transform, mesh

I have a robot arm and a Microsoft Kinect 2.0. The Kinect can output 3D point clouds, which is offset by the Kinects origo and rotation. The robot arm can move its outermost wrist to XYZ positions (and rotations) given in mm.

Imagine that the Kinect is mounted on the arm.
The robot moves to position X:0, Y: 570, Z: -950, and rotates the wrist so that the Kinect points directly downwards (rotated -90 degrees around the Z-axis).

If I get a [ColorMesh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.fusion.colormesh_members.aspx) from the Kinect, how would I rotate and offset the mesh so that it is in robot space instead of 3D camera space? I don't know much about this so any help is appreciated.

Here's an illustration of the real-life setup in mind:
The sphere denotes the workspace reach of the arm.
[image]

I was figuring the class to look something like this:

```
public class CameraToRobotCalibrator
{
    //offset in mm compared to robot origo
    public const float x_offset = 0f;
    public const float y_offset = 570f;
    public const float z_offset = -950f;

    //camera rotated around its own origo
    public const float x_rotation = 0f;
    public const float y_rotation = 0f;
    public const float z_rotation = -90f;

    public ColorMesh ConvertToRobospace(ColorMesh mesh)
    {
        //?
    }
}
```

I'm guessing if it was for 1 point it wouldn't be too hard, but I don't know about an entire mesh with vertices and faces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the specifications of the robot and its degree of freedom, you can usually calculate a 4x4 matrix that describes the endeffector's position and orientation. This is specific to the robot's design. Let's call this matrix `E`.

Then, you need to mount the Kinect on the endeffector. This will introduce another translation and possibly a rotation. So you need another matrix `M` that represents how the Kinect is mounted on the endeffector. It is the transform from the endeffector's coordinate system to the Kinect's coordinate system. Ideally, this matrix would be calibrated somehow. A good initial guess might be derived by measuring.

Then, the overall transform from the robot's root coordinate system to the Kinect coordinate system is `T = R * M` (assuming column-major matrices).

And this is the matrix that you need to transform your mesh. Transforming a mesh is just like transforming a single point. But now, you transform all vertex positions (add 1 as w-component) and all vertex normals (add 0 as w-component). Keep the face indices as they are.

Comment: I have very little experience using matrices, the last time I used them was in 2013.
If it's a 4x4 matrix, which values in the matrix would correspond to positions and which to rotation?

Comment: Then now is the time to use them again. Most robot APIs provide functions to calculate `E`. The upper left 3x3 matrix corresponds to rotation and the last column or row corresponds to position.

Comment: What do I do if one of the axes are mirrored? Say the Y axis is mirrored. Do you use a 'scale matrix' where X and Z are 1 and Y is -1?

Comment: Basically yes. But you should be sure what you are doing. Actually, this mirroring should be included in the mount matrix `M`.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in my implementation, see here:
http://pastebin.com/zfCdVFNE

You can probably find some better matrix library out there, I just use the Matrix4 from Kinect's API.

The properties were measured in real life and then calibrated after running a test with the robot and Kinect.

I figured someone might stumble upon the question some day and go 'but where is the CODE?'

I followed this guide which is basically matrices for dummies: http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx